# Ruby on Rails Pluck attribute from search and search another table with this attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, uniqueidentifier

Ok, in my Ruby on Rails application I am creating a cinema application. I am trying to implement a search where a user can click on a date, e.g. today or tomorrow, and all the films that have showings for those dates will be returned.

It is basically this: http://www.odeon.co.uk/cinemas/covent_garden/81/ where a user is able to select a different date.

I will provide my code and then explain the problem I'm having.

views/_search.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag my_path do %>
    <% date = Date.today %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :search_string, date.strftime("%F") %>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <%= submit_tag "What's on", class: "btn" %>
    </div>

    <% (1..6).each do |i| %>
      <% date = Date.today + i %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :search_string, date.strftime("%F") %>
      <%= submit_tag date.strftime("%a %D"), class: "btn" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

```
post 'films/search', to: 'films#search'
```

films_controller.rb:

```
def search
    @films = Film.date_search(params[:search_string])
    else if @films.empty?
        flash.now[:alert] = "There are no films showing with that date - Showing all films."
        @films = Film.all.order :title
    end
    render :action => "index"
end
```

film.rb:

```
def self.date_search(search_string)
    film = Showing.where("show_date = ?", search_string).pluck(:film_id)
    self.where("id = ?", film)
end
```

Associations - film.rb:

```
has_many :showings
belongs_to :certificate
belongs_to :category
```

Associations - showing.rb:

```
belongs_to :film
has_many :bookings
belongs_to :screen
```

Schema:

```
create_table "showings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date     "show_date"
  t.time     "show_time"
  t.integer  "film_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "screen_id"
end

create_table "films", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "title"
   t.string   "synopsis"
   t.string   "director"
   t.string   "cast1"
   t.string   "cast2"
   t.string   "cast3"
   t.date     "release_date"
   t.string   "warnings"
   t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
   t.string   "image_url"
   t.string   "certificate_id"
   t.integer  "category_id"
   t.integer  "hours"
   t.integer  "minutes"
   t.string   "video_url"
 end
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in FilmsController#search
SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "films" WHERE (id = 3,6)
```

I understand why I get the error but can someone please help me solve it.

Comment: `@films = Film.date_search(params[:search_string2])` - why `:search_string2` ? Should not it be `:search_string` ?

Comment: Sorry yeah you're right, I uploaded code when I was playing about with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're search method's where clause wants a single record (id) but it's getting an array:

```
def self.date_search(search_string)
  film = Showing.where("show_date = ?", search_string).pluck(:film_id)
  self.where("id = ?", film)
end
```

Should be

```
def self.date_search(search_string)
  film = Showing.where("show_date = ?", search_string).pluck(:film_id)
  # film is an ActiveRecord relation (like an array)
  self.where(id: film) # this will then run where(id IN (3, 6)), which are the values in your error in the original post 
end
```

Long and short is that your `film =` expression returns more than 1 result, so `where(id = ?)` will never run without error. It has to be an `IN`.

or

```
def self.date_search(search_string)
  film = Showing.where("show_date = ?", search_string).first.pluck(:film_id)
  # if you add .first, then it will only return one record but that may not be what you want. 
  self.where("id = ?", film)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The most immediate problem is the following line in your `date_search` method:

```
self.where("id = ?", film)
```

Since `film` is an array, the proper syntax in SQL terms should be:

```
self.where("id IN (?)", film)
```

To handle both scenarios i.e. single value as well as array, you would need this:

```
self.where(id: film)
```

**However** your `date_search` class method should actually be a scope that applies an inner join on `showings`. Here's the code:

```
# in your Film model
scope :date_search, ->(ss){ joins(:showings).where(showings: {show_date: ss}).group("films.id") }
```